# MATLAB randomly permuting columns differently

Tags: matlab, large-data

I have a very large matrix A with N rows and M columns. I want to basically do the following operation

```
for k = 1:N
    A(k,:) = A(k,randperm(M));
end
```

but fast and efficiently. (Both M and N are very large, and this is only an inner loop in a more massive outer loop.)

More context: I am trying to implement a permutation test for a correlation matrix (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resampling_%28statistics%29). My data is very large and I am very impatient. If anyone knows of a fast way to implement such a test, I would also be grateful to hear your input!

Do I have any hope of avoiding doing this in a loop?

Apologies if this has already been asked. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you type `open randperm` (at least in Matlab R2010b) you'll see that its output `p` for an input `M` is just

```
[~, p] = sort(rand(1,M));
```

So, to vectorize this for `N` rows,

```
[~, P] = sort(rand(N,M), 2);
```

Thus, generate `P` and use [linear indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/02/08/linear-indexing/) into `A`:

```
[~, P] = sort(rand(N,M), 2);
A = A(bsxfun(@plus, (1:N).', (P-1)*N));
```

Example: given

```
N = 3;
M = 4;
A = [ 1     2     3     4
      5     6     7     8
      9    10    11    12 ];
```

one (random) result is

```
A =
     2     3     1     4
     7     5     8     6
     9    11    12    10
```

Comment: Glad it worked! That was an easy one :-) I wonder why `randperm` doesn't have the option to generate multiple permutations at once this way

Comment: agreed, seems like a very simple extension!

Comment: Beware that there's a non-zero probability of collisions using this method: i.e. what if there are duplicate numbers in the output of `rand`? Also, to generate an NxM matrix like this has O(N M log(M)) time complexity, rather than the optimal O(N M). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuffling#Shuffling_algorithms

Comment: Having duplicate numbers in the output would not be a problem. `sort`  would just keep their relative order to produce the output