# Multiple sequences of random numbers without replacement

Tags: python, numpy, random

In numpy, I can use the code

```
from numpy.random import default_rng
rng = default_rng()
M, N, n = 10000, 1000, 3
rng.choice(np.arange(0, N), size=n, replace=False)
```

To get three random samples from 0 to 9 without replacement.

I would like to get thousands of such random sequences. What is the correct way to do this?
I know I can do

```
np.array([rng.choice(np.arange(0, N), size=(n,), replace=False) for i in range(0, M)])
```

but I am wondering if there's a more efficient way to do this using `numpy`.

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31958263/4007564), the following way is recommended

```
np.argsort(rng.random((M,N)),axis=1)[:, :n]
```

which is superfast and elegant. However, the cost scales like `N x M` instead of `n x M` which I am hoping to achieve.

Are there any other methods out there?

Comment: When you speak of cost, are you worried about the memory or performance?

Comment: I am worried about both but mostly the computational performance (I can reduce memory by generating the random variables in batches).

Comment: As suggested [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37012691/), you can use `np.random.rand(M,N).argpartition(n)[:,:n]`. With `argpartition` you would gain performance efficiency replacing `argsort`. Would that work for you?

Comment: Mm.. That still would scale like `N x M`. Is there no way to have something that does not scale this badly with the datum `N`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1**

For `N` >> `n`, we can use an iterative method with masking, so that at each iteration we pick one not-previously picked element per row. The implementation would look something like this -

```
R = np.arange(M)
mask = np.ones((M,N), dtype=bool)
idx = np.random.randint(0,N,(M))
mask[R,idx] = 0

for i in range(1,n):
    lim = N-i
    m2 = np.ones((M,lim), dtype=bool)
    idx2 = np.random.randint(0,lim,(M))
    m2[R,idx2] = 0
    mask[mask] = m2.ravel()

out = np.nonzero(~mask)[1].reshape(-1,n)
```

If you need to randomize numbers per row, use the rand-trick as linked in question post :

```
out = np.take_along_axis(out, np.random.rand(M,n).argsort(1), axis=1)
```

If the constant array-creation with `m2` bothers you, re-use after initializing before looping, while keeping the rest of the code same -

```
m2 = np.ones((M,N-1), dtype=bool)
for i in range(1,n):
    lim = N-i
    idx2 = np.random.randint(0,lim,(M))
    m2[R,idx2] = 0
    mask[mask] = m2.ravel()
    m2[R,idx2] = 1
    m2 = m2[:,:-1]
```

**Approach #2** Similar to `Approach #1`, but the initialization part does most of the job to setup unqiue random numbers per row. An additional `while` iterative part takes care of the rows that could not assign unique ones. With `N` >> `n`, we will hardly need to iterate though. The implementation would look something like this -

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/51915131/ @Divakar
def random_num_per_grp(L):
    # For each element in L pick a random number within range specified by it
    r1 = np.random.rand(np.sum(L)) + np.repeat(np.arange(len(L)),L)
    offset = np.r_[0,np.cumsum(L[:-1])]
    return r1.argsort()[offset] - offset

R = np.arange(M)
mask = np.ones((M,N), dtype=bool)
idx = np.random.randint(0,N,(M,n))
mask[R[:,None],idx] = 0

rows_notdone = mask.sum(1)!=N-n
while np.any(rows_notdone):    
    idx0 = random_num_per_grp(mask[rows_notdone].sum(1))
    steps = np.r_[0,mask.sum(1).cumsum()[:-1]]
    flat_idx0 = steps[rows_notdone] + idx0
    
    m2 = np.ones(mask.sum(), dtype=bool)
    m2[flat_idx0] = 0
    mask[mask] = m2
    
    rows_notdone = mask.sum(1)!=N-n

out = np.nonzero(~mask)[1].reshape(-1,n)
```

Comment: Thanks. I am marking this as the answer since it reduces the cost significantly. However, the cost scaling is still ‘MxN’ since the mask array has that size and around ‘M x (N-n)^2’ random variables are generated making it better used when ‘n’ is close to ‘N’.

Comment: @Tohiko For the mask it's actually `MxN/8`, since its a boolean array, so has a much lesser memory footprint. How did you come up with ‘M x (N-n)^2’ random variables being used? As I said, for approach #2, you hardly need to go inside while loop. So, essentially apart from the mask, you have `np.random.randint(0,N,(M,n))` and `np.nonzero` part that generates again `Mxn` array. So, a total of mask + `Mx2*n`. That's all, essentially for the memory footprint.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I was referring to Approach #1. As far as I can see, Approach #2 has a similar average case complexity (worst case being infinite).