# Efficiently compute columnwise sum of sparse array where every non-zero element is 1

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a bunch of data in [SciPy compressed sparse row (CSR)](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html) format. Of course the majority of elements is zero, and I further know that all non-zero elements have a value of 1. I want to compute sums over different subsets of rows of my matrix. At the moment I am doing the following:

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.sparse

# create some data with sparsely distributed ones
data = np.random.choice((0, 1), size=(1000, 2000), p=(0.95, 0.05))
data = sp.sparse.csr_matrix(data, dtype='int8')

# generate column-wise sums over random subsets of rows
nrand = 1000
for k in range(nrand):
    inds = np.random.choice(data.shape[0], size=100, replace=False)

    # 60% of time is spent here
    extracted_rows = data[inds]

    # 20% of time is spent here
    row_sum = extracted_rows.sum(axis=0)
```

The last few lines there are the bottleneck in a larger computational pipeline. As I annotated in the code, 60% of time is spent slicing the data from the random indices, and 20% is spent computing the actual sum.

It seems to me I should be able to use my knowledge about the data in the array (i.e., any non-zero value in the sparse matrix will be 1; no other values present) to compute these sums more efficiently. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how. Dealing with just `data.indices` perhaps? I have tried other sparsity structures (e.g. CSC matrix), as well as converting to dense array first, but these approaches were all slower than this CSR matrix approach.

Comment: Two functions that may be useful to you here are  `rows, cols = extracted_rows.nonzero()` which gives you the indices of the nonzero components and possibly `np.count_nonzero()` which counts nonzero entries in a numb array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is well known that indexing of sparse matrices is relatively slow. And there have SO questions about getting around that by accessing the data attributes directly.

But first some timings.  Using `data` and `ind` as you show I get

```
In [23]: datad=data.A  # times at 3.76 ms per loop

In [24]: timeit row_sumd=datad[inds].sum(axis=0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 529 µs per loop

In [25]: timeit row_sum=data[inds].sum(axis=0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 890 µs per loop

In [26]: timeit d=datad[inds]
10000 loops, best of 3: 55.9 µs per loop

In [27]: timeit d=data[inds]
1000 loops, best of 3: 617 µs per loop
```

The sparse version is slower than the dense one, but not by a lot.  The sparse indexing is much slower, but its sum is somewhat faster.

The sparse sum is done with a matrix product

```
def sparse.spmatrix.sum
     ....
    return np.asmatrix(np.ones((1, m), dtype=res_dtype)) * self
```

That suggests that faster way - turn `inds` into an appropriate array of 1s and multiply.

```
In [49]: %%timeit
   ....: b=np.zeros((1,data.shape[0]),'int8')
   ....: b[:,inds]=1
   ....: rowmul=b*data
   ....: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 587 µs per loop
```

That makes the sparse operation about as fast as the equivalent dense one. (but converting to dense is much slower)

==================

The last time test is missing the `np.asmatrix` that is present in the sparse `sum`.  But times are similar, and the results are the same

```
In [232]: timeit b=np.zeros((1,data.shape[0]),'int8'); b[:,inds]=1; x1=np.asmatrix(b)*data
1000 loops, best of 3: 661 µs per loop

In [233]: timeit b=np.zeros((1,data.shape[0]),'int8'); b[:,inds]=1; x2=b*data
1000 loops, best of 3: 605 µs per loop
```

One produces a matrix, the other an array. But both are doing a matrix product, 2nd dim of `B` against 1st of `data`.  Even though `b` is an array, the task is actually delegated to `data` and its matrix product - in a not so transparent a way.

```
In [234]: x1
Out[234]: matrix([[9, 9, 5, ..., 9, 5, 3]], dtype=int8)

In [235]: x2
Out[235]: array([[9, 9, 5, ..., 9, 5, 3]], dtype=int8)
```

`b*data.A` is element multiplication and raises an error; `np.dot(b,data.A)` works but is slower.

Newer `numpy/python` has a `matmul` operator.  I see the same time pattern:

```
In [280]: timeit b@dataA           # dense product
100 loops, best of 3: 2.64 ms per loop

In [281]: timeit b@data.A           # slower due to `.A` conversion
100 loops, best of 3: 6.44 ms per loop

In [282]: timeit b@data             # sparse product
1000 loops, best of 3: 571 µs per loop
```

`np.dot` may also delegate action to `sparse`, though you have to be careful.  I just hung my machine with `np.dot(csr_matrix(b),data.A)`.

Comment: This works well, and is a great speed increase! Note, however, that your code (final snippet) as such *does not run correctly*: it is essential that `b` is a Numpy `matrix`, so: `b = np.asmatrix(...)`, just as in the original `sparse.spmatrix.sum` implementation. Otherwise Numpy will try to compute elementwise product, which won't work. (Note also that `np.dot` won't work for sparse matrices, and `csr_matrix.dot` does not apply here as the CSR matrix here is on the right-hand side of the equation.) Thanks a lot!

Comment: The `asmatrix` doesn't make much of a difference.  See my edits.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a vectorized approach after converting `data` to a dense array and also getting all those `inds` in a vectorized manner using [`argpartition-based method`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31958263/3293881) -

```
# Number of selections as a parameter
n = 100

# Get inds across all iterations in a vectorized manner as a 2D array.
inds2D = np.random.rand(nrand,data.shape[0]).argpartition(n)[:,:n]

# Index into data with those 2D array indices. Then, convert to dense NumPy array, 
# reshape and sum reduce to get the final output 
out = np.array(data.todense())[inds2D.ravel()].reshape(nrand,n,-1).sum(1)
```

Runtime test -

1) Function definitions :

```
def org_app(nrand,n):
    out = np.zeros((nrand,data.shape[1]),dtype=int)
    for k in range(nrand):
        inds = np.random.choice(data.shape[0], size=n, replace=False)        
        extracted_rows = data[inds]    
        out[k] = extracted_rows.sum(axis=0)    
    return out


def vectorized_app(nrand,n):
    inds2D = np.random.rand(nrand,data.shape[0]).argpartition(n)[:,:n]
    return np.array(data.todense())[inds2D.ravel()].reshape(nrand,n,-1).sum(1)
```

Timings :

```
In [205]: # create some data with sparsely distributed ones
     ...: data = np.random.choice((0, 1), size=(1000, 2000), p=(0.95, 0.05))
     ...: data = sp.sparse.csr_matrix(data, dtype='int8')
     ...: 
     ...: # generate column-wise sums over random subsets of rows
     ...: nrand = 1000
     ...: n = 100
     ...: 

In [206]: %timeit org_app(nrand,n)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.38 s per loop

In [207]: %timeit vectorized_app(nrand,n)
1 loops, best of 3: 826 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this approach consumes too much memory in the real application.