# Extremely slow sum row operation in Sparse LIL matrix in Python

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have written this code in Python that is giving expected results but is extremely extremely slow. The bottleneck is the summing multiple rows of the scipy.sparse.lil_matrix. How can I make it fast?

```
# D1 is a 1.5M x 1.3M sparse matrix, read as scipy.sparse.lil_matrix.
# D2 is a 1.5M x 111 matrix, read as numpy.array
# F1 is a csv file, read using csv.reader

for row in F1:
    user_id = row[0]
    clust = D2[user_id, 110]
    neighbors = D2[ D2[:, 110] == clust][:,1]
    score = np.zeros(1300000)

    for neigh in neighbors:
        score = score + D1 [neigh, :] # the most expensive operation

    toBeWritten = np.argsort(score)[:,::-1].A[0,:]
```

Please let me know if there is something else too that is not very optimal.

Comment: BTW, "LIL" is short for "lists-of-lists", not "little" (although I do like the idea of a cute 'lil sparse matrix)

Comment: Thanks for the information. Edited the title

Comment: What's the typical size of `neighbors`?  Indexing operations on sparse matrices, regardless of format, are slow compared to dense arrays.

Comment: Typical size of neighbours is 5000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First a demo with a very small matrix

```
In [523]: idx=np.arange(0,8,2)
In [526]: D=np.arange(24).reshape(8,3)
In [527]: Dll=sparse.lil_matrix(D)

In [528]: D[idx,:].sum(axis=0)
Out[528]: array([36, 40, 44])

In [529]: Dll[idx,:].sum(axis=0)
Out[529]: matrix([[36, 40, 44]], dtype=int32)

In [530]: timeit D[idx,:].sum(axis=0)
100000 loops, best of 3: 17.3 µs per loop

In [531]: timeit Dll[idx,:].sum(axis=0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.16 ms per loop

In [532]: score=np.zeros(3)      # your looping version
In [533]: for i in idx:
   .....:     score = score + Dll[i,:]

In [534]: score
Out[534]: matrix([[ 36.,  40.,  44.]])

In [535]: %%timeit
   .....: score=np.zeros(3)
   .....: for i in idx:
    score = score + Dll[i,:]
   .....: 
100 loops, best of 3: 2.76 ms per loop
```

For some operations the `csr` format is faster:

```
In [537]: timeit Dll.tocsr()[idx,:].sum(axis=0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 955 µs per loop
```

or if I preconvert to csr:

```
In [538]: Dcsr=Dll.tocsr()

In [539]: timeit Dcsr[idx,:].sum(axis=0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 724 µs per loop
```

Still slow relative to dense.

I was going to talk about working with the data attributes of the sparse matrix as a way of selecting rows faster.  But if the only purpose for selecting these rows is to sum their values we don't need to do that.

Sparse matrices sum on rows or columns by doing a matrix product with a column or row matrix of ones.  And I just answered another question with the same answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37120235/901925
`Efficiently compute columnwise sum of sparse array where every non-zero element is 1`

For example:

```
In [588]: I=np.asmatrix(np.zeros((1,Dll.shape[0])))    
In [589]: I[:,idx]=1
In [590]: I
Out[590]: matrix([[ 1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.]])
In [591]: I*Dll
Out[591]: matrix([[ 36.,  40.,  44.]])

In [592]: %%timeit 
I=np.asmatrix(np.zeros((1,Dll.shape[0])))
I[:,idx]=1
I*Dll
   .....: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 919 µs per loop
```

For this small matrix it did not help the speed, but with the `Dcsr` time drops to `215 µs` (it's much better for math).  With large matrices this product version will improve.

=================

I just found out, in another question, that a `A_csr[[1,1,0,3],:]` row selection is actually done with a matrix product.  It constructs an 'extractor' csr matrix that looks like

```
matrix([[0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37245105/901925