# Numpy/Scipy broadcast calculating scalar product for a certain elements

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I've a sparse matrix like A

and a dataframe(df) with rows that should be taken to calculate scalar product.

```
Row1 Row2  Value
2    147   scalar product of vectors at Row1 and Raw2 in matrix A
```

Can I do it in broadcasting manner without looping etc?

In my case A like 1m*100k size and the dataframe 10M

Comment: Which of sparse matrix classes do you have?

Comment: doesn't matter in my case, I can easily convert it to appropriate type.

Comment: Demonstrate with a small `df` and matrix (could be dense).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with a small 'sparse' matrix (csr is the best for math):

```
In [167]: A=sparse.csr_matrix([[1, 2, 3],  # Vadim's example
               [2, 1, 4],
               [0, 2, 2],
               [3, 0, 3]])

In [168]: AA=A.A    # dense equivalent  

In [169]: idx=np.array([[1,1,0,3],[3,0,0,2]]).T  # indexes
```

I'll stick with the numpy version (Pandas is built on top of numpy)

We could take all the row dot products, and select a subset defined by `idx`:

```
In [170]: (AA.dot(AA.T))[idx[:,0], idx[:,1]]
Out[170]: array([18, 16, 14,  6], dtype=int32)
```

Sparse matrix product  (`A.dot(A.T)` also works:

```
In [171]: (A*A.T)[idx[:,0], idx[:,1]]
Out[171]: matrix([[18, 16, 14,  6]], dtype=int32)
```

Or we can select the rows first, and then take the sum of products.  We don't want to use `dot` here, since we aren't taking all combinations.

```
In [172]: (AA[idx[:,0]]*AA[idx[:,1]]).sum(axis=1)
Out[172]: array([18, 16, 14,  6], dtype=int32)
```

The `einsum` version of this calc:

```
In [180]: np.einsum('ij,ij->i',AA[idx[:,0]],AA[idx[:,1]])
Out[180]: array([18, 16, 14,  6], dtype=int32)
```

`sparse` can do the same (`*` is matrix product, `.multiply` is element by element).

```
In [173]: (A[idx[:,0]].multiply(A[idx[:,1]])).sum(axis=1)
Out[173]: 
matrix([[18],
        [16],
        [14],
        [ 6]], dtype=int32)
```

With this small case, the dense versions are faster.  Sparse row indexing is slow.

```
In [181]: timeit np.einsum('ij,ij->i', AA[idx[:,0]], AA[idx[:,1]])
100000 loops, best of 3: 18.1 µs per loop

In [182]: timeit (A[idx[:,0]].multiply(A[idx[:,1]])).sum(axis=1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.32 ms per loop

In [184]: timeit (AA.dot(AA.T))[idx[:,0], idx[:,1]]
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.62 µs per loop

In [185]: timeit (A*A.T)[idx[:,0], idx[:,1]]
1000 loops, best of 3: 689 µs per loop
```

I almost forgot - the iterative versions:

```
In [191]: timeit [AA[i].dot(AA[j]) for i,j in idx]
10000 loops, best of 3: 38.4 µs per loop

In [192]: timeit [A[i].multiply(A[j]).sum() for i,j in idx]
100 loops, best of 3: 2.58 ms per loop
```

---

Row indexing of `lil` format matrix is faster

```
In [207]: Al=A.tolil()

In [208]: timeit A[idx[:,0]]
1000 loops, best of 3: 476 µs per loop

In [209]: timeit Al[idx[:,0]]
1000 loops, best of 3: 234 µs per loop
```

But by the time it's converted back to `csr` for multiplication it might not save time.

===============

In other recent SO questions I've discussed faster ways of indexing sparse rows or columns.  But in those the final goal was to sum over a selected set of rows or columns.  For that it was actually fastest to use a matrix product - with a matrix of 1s and 0s.  Applying that idea here is a little trickier.

Looking at the `csr.__getitem__` indexing function, I find that it actually does the `A[idx,:]` indexing with a matrix product.  It creates an `extractor` matrix with function like:

```
def extractor(indices,N):
    """Return a sparse matrix P so that P*self implements
    slicing of the form self[[1,2,3],:]
    """
    indptr = np.arange(len(indices)+1, dtype=int)
    data = np.ones(len(indices), dtype=int)
    shape = (len(indices),N)
    return sparse.csr_matrix((data,indices,indptr), shape=shape)

In [328]: %%timeit
   .....: A1=extractor(idx[:,0],4)*A
   .....: A2=extractor(idx[:,1],4)*A
   .....: (A1.multiply(A2)).sum(axis=1)
   .....: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.14 ms per loop
```

This time is slightly better than that produced with `A[idx[:,0],:]` (`In[182]` above) - presumably because it is streamlining the action a bit.  It should scale in the same way.

This works because `idx0` is a boolean matrix derived from `[1,1,0,3]`

```
In [330]: extractor(idx[:,0],4).A
Out[330]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1]])

In [296]: A[idx[:,0],:].A
Out[296]: 
array([[2, 1, 4],
       [2, 1, 4],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [3, 0, 3]], dtype=int32)

In [331]: (extractor(idx[:,0],4)*A).A
Out[331]: 
array([[2, 1, 4],
       [2, 1, 4],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [3, 0, 3]], dtype=int32)
```

================

In sum, if the problem is too big to use the dense array directly, then be best bet for scaling to a large sparse case is

```
(A[idx[:,0]].multiply(A[idx[:,1]])).sum(axis=1)
```

If this is still producing memory errors, then iterate, possibly over groups of the `idx` array (or dataframe).

Comment: Part of your examples are irrelevant, I can't calculate dot product(A.dot(A.T)) because it will cause out of memory in my case. I solved it finally with A[df.Row1].multiply(A[df.Row2]).sum(axis = 1). Also it can be done with Einstein sum, but I've not tried that.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can use the `dot` function in Pandas to compute the dot product between two Series:

```
A['Row1'].dot(A['Row2'])
```

Documentation: 
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html

Comment: I'm not sure, matrix A is a scipy sparse matrix that contains coordinates of vectors. And dataframe(df) contains positions in that matrix.

Comment: That makes things even more confusing.  I don't see how a sparse matrix can contain 'coordinates of vectors'.  A sparse matrix is a matrix (2d) of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `.assign()` and `.apply()` (for pandas > 0.16.0) is suitable:

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame
from scipy.sparse import bsr_matrix

df = DataFrame(np.random.randint(4, size=(4, 2)), columns=['Row1', 'Row2'])
A = bsr_matrix([[1, 2, 3],
               [2, 1, 4],
               [0, 2, 2],
               [3, 0, 3]])

A = A.tocsr() # Skip this if your matrix is csc_, csr_, dok_ or lil_matrix
df.assign(Value=df.apply(lambda row: A[row[0]].dot(A[row[1]].transpose())[0, 0], axis=1))

Out[15]: 
   Row1  Row2  Value
0     1     3     18
1     1     0     16
2     0     0     14
3     3     2      6
```

Comment: Isn't `df.apply` a form of iteration?  With a slow sparse matrix indexing for each row of `df`?

Comment: I can't say how exactly works `df.apply` but it's definitly faster than... e.g. `df.iterrows`: applied to `df` with 10^4 rows `df.apply(lambda row:...` gives `3 loops, best of 3: 820 ms per loop` whereas the same output with `df.iterrows` - `3 loops, best of 3: 921 ms per loop`. Converting `df` to `np.matrix` and `np.apply_along_axis` is even better: `3 loops, best of 3: 709 ms per loop`. And I don't see how you can avoid slow sparse matrix indexing.

Comment: I'm familiar with how `apply_along_axis` iterates.  Looks like pandas has a little more overhead.